# Using PHP to sort data from different tables with different structure

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I need to get data from 2 different mysql tables and be able to sort by any column the user requires. I have attached my code as it is currently but can only sort by Contract Nr column. Your help will be much appreciated. I have also tried unions and joins but my query then returns no data. I did however tried the JOIN query in mysql and it worked perfectly then. Any help will be much appreciated.

TABLE contracts:

```
contracts_id | contracts_account_nr
-----------------------------------
1            | CPW001 
2            | HNP003 
3            | HNP002 
4            | CPW003 
5            | HNP001 
6            | CPW002
```

TABLE payments:

```
payments_id | contracts_id | payments_amount | payments_date
------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 2            | 150.00          | 2021-06-15
2           | 1            | 200.00          | 2021-06-16
3           | 5            | 350.00          | 2021-06-14
4           | 3            | 175.00          | 2021-06-17
5           | 3            | 240.00          | 2021-06-11
6           | 4            | 295.00          | 2021-06-13
7           | 6            | 140.00          | 2021-06-12
8           | 1            | 210.00          | 2021-06-15
```

My current code with which I can sort the Account NR but have no idea how to include other columns to sort.

```
    $orderBy = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? $_GET["orderby"] : "contracts_account_nr";
    $order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? $_GET["order"] : "asc";
    $sql = "SELECT contracts_id, contracts_account_nr FROM contracts ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    $contractOrder = "asc"; 
    $dateOrder = "asc"; 
    if($orderBy == "contracts_account_nr" && $order == "asc") {
    $contractOrder = "desc";    
    }
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contract Nr &nbsp;<a href="?orderby=contracts_account_nr&order=<?php echo $contractOrder; ?>" title="Sort"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php   
    if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $contractid = $row['contracts_id'];
    $contractnr = $row['contracts_account_nr']; 
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE contracts_id = '$contractid'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);   
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {  
    ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $contractnr; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo "R " .  number_format((float)$row1['payments_amount'], 2, '.', ' '); ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $row1['payments_date']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have tried the following code using JOIN but it didn't return any results or errors, but did work perfectly as a sql query in mysql:

```
$sql = "SELECT contract.contracts_account_nr, payment.rental_payment_type, 
payment.payment_amount, payment.rental_payment_date, payment.rental_payment_option FROM `contracts` AS contract LEFT JOIN 
`payments` AS payment ON contract.contracts_id = payment.contracts_id ORDER BY contract.contracts_account_nr DESC";

?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contract Nr</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Date</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php   
    if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['contract.contracts_account_nr']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['payment.payments_amount']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['payment.payments_date']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    
    ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your system is open to SQL injection attacks. You should compare the column names and sort directions to a whitelist to make sure only valid column names and directions can be entered.

Comment: Call `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` before you use mysqli.  You may be getting errors from your SQL. I had to mess around with it a lot to get it to work. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65364Tkdj5nYSkGWjBJtXV/0

Comment: i started reading reading your code but had to give up because my eyes were burning. Don't nest queries like this. when you open your fourth set of curly brackets its time to restructure your code. Don't swap in and out of blocks of HTML - embed your HTML in PHP or embed your PHP in HTML. Either use the procedural API or the OO API, don't mix and match.  Be consistent with your indentation. Wrap your code. Do read up on SQL Injection Please read some papers on good programming style.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you for your help. I've managed to sort my code and the query now returns the correct data as required.